# struts 1, properties file

Tags: java, file, jsp, struts, properties

I have a selection box in a struts 1 JSP file. In that selection box I have to retrieve its selection from the key values in the properties file. Any ideas?

Comment: Give it a try and let us know if you run into any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a properties file using *java.util.Properties* and inject some request attributes  from an Action or inject the properties in the ActionForm.

Comment: i need to get only few properties . can we use any tas